# Elliptic regularity for Dirichlet problem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, boundary-value-problems

Let $\overline{M}=M \cup \partial M$ be a compact manifold with boundary, where $\partial M$ is the boundary of $\overline{M}$ and $M$ is the interior of $\overline{M}$.
Let $P$ be an injective elliptic partial differential operator of order $2$ on $\overline{M}$.

For $k\geq 0$, let $u \in H^{2+k}$, the $L^2$-Sobolev space with $(2+k)$ weak derivatives.
Assume that $Pu=f$ on $M$ and assume that $u|_{\partial M}=0$.

> Question:
> Do we have (like in the case of compact manifolds without boundary, where we even have a slightly stronger estimate) an interior estimate of the form
> $$
> ||u||_{H^{2+k}}^2
> \leq
> C
> (
> ||Pu||_{H^k}^2
> +
> ||u||^2_{H^{1+k}})?
> $$

*Taylor: Partial Differential Equations I - Basic Theory* contains information about this that I don't understand.
Equation (11.29) in Section 5 is what I want, but there is no statement that it holds in my case.

If $P$ has even degree and is strongly elliptic, which I'm happy to assume, then Proposition 11.10 in Section 5 states that the Dirichlet boundary condition is regular.
Proposition 11.14 in Section 5 then gives an estimate in some complicated norms on a collar neighbourhood, but not the whole manifold with boundary.

Can you recommend another reference for this material?

This is crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4882733/elliptic-regularity-for-dirichlet-problem .

Comment: I don't think that the manifold nor its boundary play a real role here since you assume $\overline{M}$ to be compact. Those estimates are true locally on balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and in half-balls with Dirichlet data on the flat part of the boundary. Just cover $\overline{M}$ with finitely many small balls (or half-balls, the one on the boundary) and pass to charts to get what you ask using just the result for flat $\mathbb{R}^n$.